# Merging resources tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

1) free-online-resources tag (has just one question) can be merged to online-resources. 
2) resources tag and resource-request tag be merged or have their tag wiki better defined and differentiated?
3) what about potential tags which are used *rarely* like 'mooc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If a tag has just one question, and it is very similar to another tag that has many questions, I recommend just deleting the used-once tag. When searching, for example, one can always search for "[online-resources] free" to scratch that itch.
2. Looking at the questions, I think [resources] and [resource-request] can be merged.
3. If the concepts behind them are sufficiently unique and well-defined, I prefer to let them be as they are.

Comment: ok, what about _Also can resources and resource request be merged or have their tag wiki better defined and differentiated?_

Comment: Please check out update in the question.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak updated my answer too.

Comment: Can I merge them in by any means? (referring to (2) )

Comment: I mean i only have 440 rep which is less than 1250

Comment: @WiccanKarnak I have merged them now.

Comment: can you please add 'status-completed' to the above question?